# How to send interactive prompt response in linux shell?

Tags: shell, prompt

I'm trying to make a script that automatically zips a file with a password. Zip does this by asking for a password in an interactive prompt. How do I make the script respond to the prompt?

I've tried:

## zip -e xxx myfile

Enter password:

zip error: Interrupted (aborting)

## zip -e myfile < xxx

-bash: xxx: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

The -e option expects that `zip` is running on a terminal.  You can use a pseudo-terminal and script that (using the Expect package available in Tcl or Perl or something similar) if you don't mind the complexity.

It might be easier to use the -P flag (or --password) flag with zip, and just pass the password on the command line.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The version of zip I've got doesn't come with a -P or --password option and you're right that a pseudo-terminal is probably too complex to be worth it. I guess I'll encrypt the file another way.